# WCF Service Accepting GZip Messages

Tags: c#, wcf

I am probably missing the obvious, but how can I make it so that one method, PutMessage, on my WCF service can accept both GZip'd and normal requests? Right now I'm seeing this error from my service:

```
Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/gzip' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'.
```

I've tried adding a custom binding with binaryMessageCoding/compressionFormat="GZip" and httpTransport. Does this need multiple bindings and multiple endpoints configured? Or multiple bindings and one endpoint? One endpoint and one binding?

I can't change the sending code since it's a third-party that I don't have access to.

Here is my Web.config so far:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="UserNameAuthenticationBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="API.Star.XXXUsernamePasswordValidator, API" />
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="API.Star.starTransport">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <customBinding>
        <binding name="API.Star.starTransportGzip">
          <binaryMessageEncoding compressionFormat="GZip" />
          <httpTransport />
        </binding>
      </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="API.Star.StarWebService" behaviorConfiguration="UserNameAuthenticationBehaviour">
        <endpoint name="StarWebServiceEndpoint" address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="API.Star.starTransport" contract="API.Star.operations" bindingNamespace="http://www.starstandards.org/webservices/2005/10/transport" />
        <endpoint name="StarWebServiceEndpointGzip" address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="API.Star.starTransportGzip" contract="API.Star.operations" bindingNamespace="http://www.starstandards.org/webservices/2005/10/transport" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything special for .NET 4+ when you host your service on IIS. You simply need to enable HTTP Compression on IIS.

Check the section on Http Decompression in [What's New in WCF 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456789%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for some links on how to [enable HTTP compression in IIS 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771003%28WS.10%29.aspx).

In WCF 4.5 you get compression support for the binary encoder as well. Check the section [Compression and the Binary Encoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456789%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I think that might be where I'm confused. The IIS settings seemed to be around GZip *responses*, not *requests*.

Comment: I made sure that Compression is enabled on IIS and included */* as an enabled dynamic type, but the error is still occurring.

Comment: The request gets generated by the client, not the service. It's up to the client to create a request that uses GZip.

Comment: The client IS using GZip for some requests-- the error indicates that the service won't accept it.

Comment: This is only true if you have .NET client. But if your source is example SOAPUI, it doesn't work out of the box.

Comment: @richterbelmont what do you refer to? HTTP Response compression isn't related to .NET, you just need to specify the proper request headers. On the other hand HTTP doesn't support HTTP *request* compression so clients and servers have to implement a custom format. That's what the binary encoder does.

Comment: @SOreadytohelp HTTP does implement request compression using Gzip. I tried this using soapui. The binaryencoding compression which comes out of the box of WCF doesn't know how to decompress this. You can see this in more detail here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37402492/how-to-process-gzip-from-soapui-in-wcf