# How to process gzip from SoapUI in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, soapui

I am working on two way gzip compression in my WCF. The response part is fairly easy with IIS but I can't seem to handle a request using SoapUI. The reason I'm using SoapUI is because the client app that will be connecting won't be using Microsoft stack on their end.

I have created a sample solution here to demonstrate the promlem
https://github.com/janmchan/WCFCompression

In the solution I have a WCFServiceDemo (WCF Server) and WCFClient (WCF Client). Using the binding below for both client / server, I don't have any issue with request / response.

```
<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <binding name="myBinding">
      <binaryMessageEncoding compressionFormat="GZip"/>
      <httpTransport decompressionEnabled="True" />
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
```

I get the following header with this request

```
2016-05-23 11:37;14 : Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 298
Content-Type: application/soap+msbin1+gzip
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Expect: 100-continue
Host: localhost:19860
```

However, using SoapUI with these settings

[image]

and this sample message

[image]

I get the following response which suggest the content type is incorrect. I've tried adding the headers but it doesn't seem to be the solution. I also tried adding a module to add the filter for Gzip compression, but it still encouters an error after exiting all the modules.

How do I make sure that and end client can connect to the WCF similar to how SoapUI is connecting?

```
HTTP/1.1 415 Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action="http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData"' was not the expected type 'application/soap+msbin1+gzip' Cache-Control: private
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?YzpcdXNlcnNcamNoYW5cZG9jdW1lbnRzXHZpc3VhbCBzdHVkaW8gMjAxNVxQcm9qZWN0c1xXY2ZTZXJ2aWNlRGVtb1xXY2ZTZXJ2aWNlRGVtb1xTZXJ2aWNlMS5zdmM=?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 24 May 2016 00:04:19 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through several options, I discovered that the best way to resolve this is to use a custom MessageEncoder. Although I have a working sample [here](https://github.com/janmchan/WCFCompression), I still have an issue where some headers are missing but essentially when this is resolved, it should be the solution to this problem.

[Why are the soap headers missing when using Custom MessageEncoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37495848/why-are-the-soap-headers-missing-when-using-custom-messageencoder)